# Using Firebase for AR in Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, cloud, augmented-reality

Can Firebase be used to store a target marker for AR Unity?

I have seen that it could store an image when uploaded from phone to its cloud service, but not much about syncing the image (target marker) with the app. I know that Vuforia can be used to store database, but can Firebase do the same thing using its cloud features?

Comment: if i got it true - you need an markerless ar ? its true ?

Comment: no, just a pattern/image that serves as a target marker.

Comment: can you share a video from youtube near to what you want ?